# R predicts less instances that the dataset

Tags: r, matrix, r-caret, predict

I am creating a predictive model in R with "caret" and I don't understand how the function "predict" works.

I have a dataset testing with 222 instances, but when I execute the next command:

```
j48Probs <- predict(j48Model3x10cv, newdata = testing, type = "prob")
```

j48probs have 178 elements, and when I try to get the confusion matrix, I get the next error:

```
j48Classes <- predict(j48Model3x10cv, newdata = testing, type = "raw")
confusionMatrix(data=j48Classes, testing$Survived)

Error in table(data, reference, dnn = dnn, ...) : 
all arguments must have the same length
```

What can be happening?

Thank you so much!

Comment: Are there missing values in your data?

Comment: There are missing values in the train dataset

Answer (score 0):

There have to be missing values in your testing set. One of the options in predict is na.action and this is standard set to na.omit. Which means any record containing missing data in one of the predictors will be ignored.

Take your testing data set and do `nrow(na.omit(testing)`. It will show you how many rows will be used for prediction. In your case this probably returns 177 records.

And this issue rolls over into the confusionmatrix, you are trying to compare 177 predictions against 222 labels.

You could set na.action = NULL, but this will return NA predictions. That might or might not make sense. In some cases not being able to predict a classification is also information. You could also try imputing the missing data.

Answer (score 0):

If the problem is that in the predictions there are many instances omited because of the missing values, I consider two solutions:

1.- not to omit them.
2.- omit them in the testing set too.

1.- I solved that this way:

```
j48Probs <- predict(j48Model3x10cv, newdata = testing, type = "prob", na.action = na.pass)

j48Classes <- predict(j48Model3x10cv, newdata = testing, type = "raw", na.action = na.pass)
confusionMatrix(data=j48Classes, testing$Survived)
```

2.- I solved this way:

```
testing <- (na.omit(testing)
```